# How to Config Saved CC Payment Gateway Configuration as Live?

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway

I am checking Saved CC (Default payment Gateway) using dummy data. It's working fine but I want make it live. We can not validate dummy data in this. Where can I set merchant account Saved CC. I am very confused. Can you give step and example url for that. Means live Magento store setup this gateway.

Comment: You are using any third party payment gateway?

Comment: no default magento Saved CC.